# Spring security global-method-security doesn't work in OSGI environment

Tags: methods, spring-security, osgi, bundle, protected

I tried to use spring security to protect my osgi service and web application, the intercept-url works fine, but the global method security doesn't work at all. For pure OSGI bundle, proxy mode doesn't work, since spring-beans cannot access SpringProxy. I tried both proxy mode and aspectj mode, and enabled load time weaving in aspectj mode, the bundle was successfully loaded. But the Preauthorized doesn't work(pre-post-annotations="enabled" was added in xml configuration), and the annotation added both on interface and implementation, still it doesn't work.

I don't know the mechanism of the spring security for protecting bean methods. Is there anybody can give me some hint? Thank you!

Comment: I debuged into the code, it seems the issue is because each bundle has its own classload, and PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource checks Pre post annotations from its own bundle, so it cannot find my business class. It seems the probable solution is to define a custom SecurityMetadataSource in my own bundle. I used the same technique to solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, by default context:component-scan will not generate proxy for beans generated.

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="org.ops4j.pax.web.samples.spring.service" scoped-proxy="targetClass/interfaces" />
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, the issue is not because proxy, but the mechanism of bean creating in component-scan

Comment: It's really sad that there is bug in spring-osgi-io when search classes defined in component-scan

Answer (score 0):

It's really sad that there is bug in spring-osgi-io when search classes defined in component-scan OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver. The class path is removed from beginning, so in step 2, it search bundle root folder, not classpath

// eliminate classpath path
        final String path = OsgiResourceUtils.stripPrefix(locationPattern);

```
    final Collection foundPaths = new LinkedHashSet();

    // 1. search the imported packages

    // find folder path matching 
    final String rootDirPath = determineFolderPattern(path);

    if (System.getSecurityManager() != null) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

            public Object run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < importedBundles.length; i++) {
                    final ImportedBundle importedBundle = importedBundles[i];
                    if (!bundle.equals(importedBundle.getBundle())) {
                        findImportedBundleMatchingResource(importedBundle, rootDirPath, path, foundPaths);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < importedBundles.length; i++) {
            final ImportedBundle importedBundle = importedBundles[i];
            if (!bundle.equals(importedBundle.getBundle())) {
                findImportedBundleMatchingResource(importedBundle, rootDirPath, path, foundPaths);
            }
        }
    }

    // 2. search the target bundle
    findSyntheticClassPathMatchingResource(bundle, path, foundPaths);
```

Comment: It's really sad that in 2015 people still think classpath scanning is a viable approach.